# Magento 1.9 Changing Totals Layout and Calculations

Tags: magento-1.9, order-totals

I want to change to layout of order totals on review, print, email and admin panel
somehow i manage to do that with cod fee its showing perfect as screenshot attached 
COD Fee
Vat (5%)
Subtotal
Same i want to do that with 
Shipping and Subtotal of products 
from the backend i mange to bring price with and without tax but showing tax in separte line for each total ( subtotal and shipping total )

also i want to remove that tax line

[image: Order Review Screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved by combining some tricks 
First, make tax rule 5% for shipping class in Magento back office

then create a copy of core file in local

This "app\code\core\Mage\Tax\Block\Sales\Order\Tax.php"

into this  "app\code\local\Mage\Tax\Block\Sales\Order\Tax.php"

because we should never edit the core file directly, we can override them by placing in the local folder with the same path

in function _initSubtotal()

Change this

```
       $totalExcl = new Varien_Object(array(
            'code'      => 'subtotal_excl',
            'value'     => $subtotal,
            'base_value'=> $baseSubtotal,
            'label'     => $this->__('Subtotal (Excl.Tax)')
        ));
        $totalIncl = new Varien_Object(array(
            'code'      => 'subtotal_incl',
            'value'     => $subtotalIncl,
            'base_value'=> $baseSubtotalIncl,
            'label'     => $this->__('Subtotal (Incl.Tax)')
        ));
        $parent->addTotal($totalExcl, 'subtotal');
        $parent->addTotal($totalIncl, 'subtotal_excl');
```

To This

```
        $totalExcl = new Varien_Object(array(
            'code'      => 'subtotal_excl',
            'value'     => $subtotal,
            'base_value'=> $baseSubtotal,
            'label'     => $this->__('Product RSP (Net)')
        ));
        $subtotal_vat= ($subtotal* 0.05);
        $base_subtotal_vat= ($baseSubtotal* 0.05);
        $totalVat = new Varien_Object(array(
            'code'      => 'subtotal_vat',
            'value'     => $subtotal_vat,   
            'base_value'=> $base_subtotal_vat,
            'label'     => $this->__('VAT (5%)')
        ));
        $totalIncl = new Varien_Object(array(
            'code'      => 'subtotal_incl',
            'value'     => $subtotalIncl,
            'base_value'=> $baseSubtotalIncl,
            'label'     => $this->__('Subtotal')
        ));
        $parent->addTotal($totalExcl, 'subtotal');
        $parent->addTotal($totalVat, 'subtotal_excl');
        $parent->addTotal($totalIncl, 'subtotal_vat');
```

That will do the job for the subtotal of products 
Now let's move on to shipping

same file function _initShipping()
Change this

```
        $totalExcl = new Varien_Object(array(
            'code'      => 'shipping',
            'value'     => $shipping,
            'base_value'=> $baseShipping,
            'label'     => $this->__('Shipping & Handling (Excl.Tax)')
        ));
        $totalIncl = new Varien_Object(array(
            'code'      => 'shipping_incl',
            'value'     => $shippingIncl,
            'base_value'=> $baseShippingIncl,
            'label'     => $this->__('Shipping & Handling (Incl.Tax)')
        ));
        $parent->addTotal($totalExcl, 'shipping');
        $parent->addTotal($totalIncl, 'shipping');
```

To this

```
        $totalExcl = new Varien_Object(array(
            'code'      => 'shipping_excl',
            'value'     => $shipping,
            'base_value'=> $baseShipping,
            'label'     => $this->__('Shipping & Handling')
        ));
        $shipping_vat = ($shipping * 0.05);
        $base_shipping_vat= ($baseShipping* 0.05);
        $totalVat = new Varien_Object(array(
            'code'      => 'shipping_vat',
            'value'     => $shipping_vat,  // this can be easily calculated
            'base_value'=> $base_shipping_vat,
            'label'     => $this->__('VAT (5%)')
        ));
        $totalIncl = new Varien_Object(array(
            'code'      => 'shipping_incl',
            'value'     => $shippingIncl,
            'base_value'=> $baseShippingIncl,
            'label'     => $this->__('Subtotal')
        ));
        $parent->addTotal($totalExcl, 'shipping');
        $parent->addTotal($totalVat,  'shipping_excl');
        $parent->addTotal($totalIncl, 'shipping_vat');
```

Removing tax is the easy part

app\design\frontend[your-theme-name]\default\template\tax\checkout\tax.phtml

if file is not present then just copy that from base 
Just comment out every code in that file in your theme